# Unexpected response when using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've been coding a simple API with the view of getting placeholder image of a specialized site which offers this service. However, when I make a request to site with correspondent path,  I'm not able of  getting the image displayed on screen instead I got this HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/">http://fakeimg.pl/300x300/</a>. If not click the link.
```

I read the official documentation all day long but up to now I haven't realized a way to get this work properly.

This is my code. Obs: I have used the url "https://fakeimg.pl/300X300" and the dotnet core version 3.1.302 for this sample request.

FakePhotoService.cs

```cs
namespace FakePhotoApi
{
    public class FakePhotoService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly ILogger<FakePhotoService> _logger;

        public FakePhotoService(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger<FakePhotoService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public HttpRequestMessage GenerateRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            return new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        }

        public async Task<string> GetFakePhoto(Tuple<int, int> dimensions)
        {
            var baseUri = new Uri($"https://fakeimg.pl/{dimensions.Item1}x{dimensions.Item2}");
            var request = GenerateRequest(baseUri);
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

FakePhotoController.cs

```cs
namespace FakePhotoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FakePhotoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly FakePhotoService _fakePhotoService;

        public FakePhotoController(FakePhotoService fakePhotoService)
        {
            _fakePhotoService = fakePhotoService;
        }
        [HttpGet("/")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFakePhoto()
        {
            var result = await _fakePhotoService.GetFakePhoto(new Tuple<int, int>(300, 300));
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```cs
namespace FakePhotoApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHttpClient<FakePhotoService>()
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
            {
                return new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                    MaxAutomaticRedirections = 5
                };
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
namespace FakePhotoApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: investigate the response status code and headers.

Comment: The fakeimg.pl image url expects `/` at the end of it. If you browse `https://fakeimg.pl/300x300` in the browser and inspect the network trace in fiddler or browser tools, it returns response 308 with the same response content as you are getting. After that another redirection with 301 status happens to `https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/` URL which returns the actual image. [Capture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIVT3.png). But if you browse the URL `https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/` it returns the image directly without any redirection. [Capture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Mvf.png).

Comment: So all you need to do is change `$"https://fakeimg.pl/{dimensions.Item1}x{dimensions.Item2}"` to `$"https://fakeimg.pl/{dimensions.Item1}x{dimensions.Item2}/"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like so:

```
public HttpRequestMessage GenerateRequest(Uri uri)
{
    var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    msg.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"); // or some other real browser string
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: Adding the User-Agent to the request and a trailing forward slash on the url path solved my issue.